# Adding tag script with react and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, api

I'm trying to add a script tag from Spotify to the page. For that, I'm using `useEffect`, but when I try to get the class Spotify, it cannot be found (I'm using ReactJS and Typescript):

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
      
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
      
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      
        return () => {
          document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
      }, []);

(window as any).onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        const token = '[My Spotify Web API access token]';
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
          name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
          getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Have you `import`ed the variable `Spotify` in the scope? Please, include the lines with `require` functions and `import` keywords

Answer (score -1):

For external scripts added with script tags, you should define a variable in the global scope to be recognized by typescript.

```
declare var Spotify:any;
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question, in a code like this"player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message } ) => { console.error(message); });", how i declare the type of "`{message}" ?